# how to access npm registry data from my node app

Tags: node.js

I want to access npm registry from my nodejs app and retrieve say module/package name and git url for each of the modules/packages. How do I go about getting this npm registry data ? Do we have some existing modules that would help me do that ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I programmatically use the system copy of npm (instead of installing a separate copy of npm just to use it programmatically):

```
function loadNpm(cb) {
  require('child_process').exec('npm', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    var m = /npm@[^ ]+ (.+)\n/i.exec(stdout);
    if (!m)
      return cb(new Error('Unable to find path in npm help message'));
    cb(undefined, require(m[1]));
  });
}

// usage ...
loadNpm(function(err, npm) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // load() is required before using npm API
  npm.load(function(err, npm) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // e.g. npm.search('ssh', true, function(err, results) { console.dir(results); });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. The very idea of fetching the registry module data is for the below I'm trying to achieve. I want to pull up the npm module statistics from the github repository. we want to know the most reliable npm modules to further use in the implementation hence would like to pull up a list of npm module name, github open and closed issue count.

Comment: So,trying to fetch the npm modules from the registry and based on the modulename/owner name, fetch the repository data from github. Not sure if there is an easier way than going through this way.

Comment: If that's all you want, you can get json out of the registry itself since it's just running CouchDB. Or you can use some module like [npm-stats](https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm-stats) to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Thank you. If you have sample code accessing npm-stats module, pls.post it. This code segment is throwing an error - 'has no method listByDate'. var npmReg = require('npm-stats'); var fromDate = "2012-10-01"; var toDate= "2014-04-01"; console.log(registry.listByDate ({since:fromDate,until:toDate}));

Comment: sorry..the code segment has two diff. variables..Error pertains.    var npmReg = require('npm-stats');
    var fromDate = "2012-10-01";
    var toDate= "2014-04-01";
    console.log(npmReg.list());

Comment: @user3537627 Since you're using `npmReg` and not `registry`, you have to use `npmReg.listByDate` instead. Also `listByDate()` [takes a callback](https://github.com/hughsk/npm-stats/blob/master/lib/registry.js#L13) as do most of the others. The callback has the standard (err, result) format.

Comment: i fixed the variables and ran earlier but still the same issue...provided callback too..wish the module authors do provide example code that exercise their code ! some modules do have the example support..it's easier to test out quickly without many firsttime errors.

Comment: username:@mscdex i fixed the variables and ran earlier but still the same issue...provided callback too..wish the module authors do provide example code that exercise their code ! some modules do have the example support..it's easier to test out quickly without many firsttime error

Comment: I don't know then. You can easily see in their source code what the URLs and parameters are, so you could just do it yourself if nothing else. You might also try browsing npm/github for simiular npm stats modules.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the child-process module to execute npm.  Here is a code sample from the node web site:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
child;

child = exec('cat *.js bad_file | wc -l',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, but npm itself [is an npm module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm). See the Using npm Programmatically section for how you might do this.